# Selecting Priors for the Function sdPrior() to include in a Bayesian Time Series Analysis with MCMC using the BSTS Package with a Poisson Response

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

**Overview**

I am conducting a **Bayesian time series analysis** using the **bsts package** that incorporates **mcmc simulations** with a **Poisson response** for counts of birds.

**The predictors are (see data frame BSTS_df below):**

1. Year - numeric
2. Month - categorical

**The response variable is Frequency (counts of birds)**

I am following this tutorial below:

https://michaeldewittjr.com/dewitt_blog/posts/2018-07-05-bayesian-time-series-analysis-with-bsts_files/

The **default priors** selected when you **AddLocalLevel or AddSeasonal** typically assume that you're working with Gaussian data.  Therefore, I need to directly supply priors using **SdPrior()** when you call **AddSomeComponent** because my data is **Poisson distributed**.

**Issue**

I cannot find any **R help tutorials online** that aids to select prior values to input into the function **sdPrior()**, which will ultimately produces the model of **best fit** with the **lowest mean absolute percentage error (MAPE) value**. Additionally, I cannot find any tutorials regarding running bsts with a **Poisson response**.

My **MAPE** values are **very high (see plot below)**, so I need to **adjust the prior values** to produce the lowest **MAPE**. I am also not an advanced R user with advanced knowledge of Bayesian statistics. In this case, I feel that I need to ask an expert for help to point me in the right direction.

**Question**

**Is there a pre-processing method to set-up the Bayesian priors for the best model (running many models) when you do not have clear priors?**

If anyone can help me, I would like to express my deepest appreciation because I am struggling.

Many thanks in advance.

**R-code**

```
##########################################################################################
########Time series analysis
########Bayesian regression with MCMC 
##########################################################################################

* 500 MCMC draws.
* Use 2017 as the holdout period.
* Trend and seasonality.
* Forecast created by averaging across the MCMC draws. 
* Credible interval generated from the distribution of the MCMC draws.
* Discarding the first MCMC iterations (burn-in).
* Using a log transformation to make the model multiplicative

    #################################################################################
    ##Time Series Bayesian Inference Model with mcmc using the bsts() function
    ##################################################################################
    
    #Set seed
    
    set.seed(45L)
    
    ##Open packages for the time series analysis
    
    library(lubridate)
    library(bsts)
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(ggfortify)
    library(forecast)
    
    ##Change the Year column into YY/MM/DD format for the first of evey month per year
    BSTS_df$Year <- lubridate::ymd(paste0(BSTS_df$Year, BSTS_df$Month,"-01"))
    
    ##Order the Year column in YY/MM/DD format into the correct sequence: Jan-Dec
    allDates <- seq.Date(
                        min(BSTS_df$Year),
                        max(BSTS_df$Year),
                       "month")
    
    ##Produce and arrange the new data frame ordered by the first of evey month in YY/MM/DD format
    BSTS_new_df <- BSTS_df %>%
                          right_join(data.frame(Year = allDates), by = c("Year")) %>%
                          dplyr::arrange(Year) %>%
                          tidyr::fill(Frequency, .direction = "down")
    
    ##Calculate the mean count per month over 3 years
    
    BSTS_new_df %>% group_by(the_month = month(Year)) %>% summarize(Avg = mean(Frequency))
    
    #########################################################################################
    
    
    ##Create a time series object
    myts2 <- ts(BSTS_new_df$Frequency, start=c(2015, 1), end=c(2017, 12), frequency=12)
    
    ##Upload the data into the windows() function
    x <- window(myts2, start=c(2015, 01), end=c(2016, 12))
    y <- x
    
    ##Set priors
    
    sdy <- sd(BSTS_new_df$Frequency)
    
    sigma.prior <- SdPrior(sigma.guess=0.01*sdy,
                           upper.limit=sdy,
                           sample.size=36)
    
    ##Produce a list for the object ss
    ss <- list()
    
    #ss <- AddLocalLinearTrend(list(), y)
    ss <- AddSeasonal(ss, y, nseasons = 12)
    ss <- AddLocalLevel(ss, y, sigma.prior)  
                        
    # bsts.model <- bsts(y, state.specification = ss, family = "poisson", niter = 2, ping=0, seed=1234)
    # If these are poisson distributed, no need to use logit because it bounds reponse
    # between 0-1
    
    bsts.model<-bsts(y, state.specification = ss, niter=100, family="poisson", ping=0, seed = 123)
    
    ##Open plotting window
    dev.new()
    
    ##Plot the bsts.model
    plot(bsts.model)
    
    ##Open a new plotting window
    dev.new()
    
    ##Plot the components
    plot(bsts.model, "components")
    
    ##Make the predictions for the bsts model
    predict<-predict(bsts.model, horizon=12)
    
    predict
    
    ##Open plotting window
    dev.new()
    
    ##Plot the predictions
    plot(predict)
    
    ##Get a suggested number of burns
    burn<-bsts::SuggestBurn(0.1, bsts.model)
    
    ##Predict
    p<-predict.bsts(bsts.model, horizon = 12, burn=burn, quantiles=c(.25, .975))
    
    p$mean
    
    ##Actual vs predicted
    
    d2 <- data.frame(
      # fitted values and predictions
       c(as.numeric(-colMeans(bsts.model$one.step.prediction.errors[-(1:burn),])+y),  
         as.numeric(p$mean)),
      # actual data and dates
        as.numeric(BSTS_new_df$Frequency),
        as.Date(BSTS_new_df$Year))
    
    ###Rename the columns
    names(d2) <- c("Fitted", "Actual", "Date")
    
    d2
    
    ##Sum the fitted column in d2
    Fitted_Sum<-sum(d2$Fitted)
    
    ##Sum the actual column in d2
    Actual_Sum<-sum(d2$Actual)
    
    ### MAPE(mean absolute percentage error)
    
    MAPE<-mean(abs(Actual_Sum-Fitted_Sum)/abs(Actual_Sum))
    
    MAPE
      
    ### 95% forecast credible interval
    posterior.interval <- cbind.data.frame(
                                      as.numeric(p$interval[1,]),
                                      as.numeric(p$interval[2,]),
                                      tail(d2,12)$Date)
    
    ##Rename the columns
    names(posterior.interval) <- c("LL", "UL", "Date")
    
    posterior.interval
    
    ### Join intervals to the forecast
    d3 <- left_join(d2, posterior.interval, by="Date")
    
    ##Open plotting window
    dev.new()
    
    ### Plot actual versus predicted with credible intervals for the holdout period
    ggplot(data=d3, aes(x=Date)) +
           geom_line(aes(y=Actual, colour = "Actual"), size=1.2) +
           geom_line(aes(y=Fitted, colour = "Fitted"), size=1.2, linetype=2) +
           theme_bw() + theme(legend.title = element_blank()) + ylab("") + xlab("") +
           geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(as.Date("2017-12-01")), linetype=2) +
           geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=LL, ymax=UL), fill="grey", alpha=0.5) +
           ggtitle(paste0("BSTS -- Holdout MAPE = ", round(100*MAPE,2), "%")) +
           theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0))
```

**Plot showing a high MAPE value**

[image]

**Data frame - BSTS_df**

```
structure(list(Year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017), Month = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 
9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 
2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L), .Label = c("April", "August", "December", 
"February", "January", "July", "June", "March", "May", "November", 
"October", "September"), class = "factor"), Frequency = c(36, 
28, 39, 46, 5, 0, 0, 22, 10, 15, 8, 33, 33, 29, 31, 23, 8, 9, 
7, 40, 41, 41, 30, 30, 44, 37, 41, 42, 20, 0, 7, 27, 35, 27, 
43, 38), Days_Sea_Month = c(31, 28, 31, 30, 6, 0, 0, 29, 15, 
29, 29, 31, 31, 29, 30, 30, 7, 0, 7, 30, 30, 31, 30, 27, 31, 
28, 30, 30, 21, 0, 7, 26, 29, 27, 29, 29)), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = "data.frame")
```